# How to set datasource for MySQL database in Microsoft SQL Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0. And I have remote Linux Server(with certain IP) that have MySQL database. I want connect this MySQL database from Report Builder (in my PC), So that I can create some reports about it. How can i do that? Please help and Thanks.

Comment: It's the same as any other data source. Select the proper driver, enter the server's name, database etc. This assumes that you *have* installed a MySQL driver, preferabley OLEDB

Comment: I think you must do it via ODBC DSN, I wrote an answer with detailed specification of every task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to download and install (32-bit or 64-bit) appropriate MySQL connector.

[MySQL ODBC connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html)

After installation, you need to create ODBC Data Source Name (DSN) on this way:

1. Open **Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> ODBC Data Sources** (32-bit or 64-bit, depending of installed connector)
2. **Choose System DSN** tab and click on **Add**
3. In dialog window, choose installed connector for MySQL
4. In new dialog window populate Data source name field with descriptive name, fill MySQL server address and port (IP address or server network name) and fill credentials that have enough permissions to MySQL server. **Catalog** field is optional field. Test the connection.
5. Open Microsoft Report Builder 3.0, and create new report. While creating dataset, you need to choose data source. Click **New Data Source** (or just **New**) and in the dialog window for **Connection type**, choose **ODBC** and in the Connection string choose **Build** option.
6. In new dialog window, in **Data source specification** section choose your DSN that you created in stages 2, 3 and 4 and test connection.
7. Voila :)

Comment: Thanks man. It worked after little effort from my internal site. Anyway thanks.

Comment: I had problem when connecting to the data source in Microsoft Report Builder and when I installed both 32-bit and 64-bit version of MySQL ODBC connector the problem resolved.